# Java program that prints a string backwards

Tags: java, string, character

I'm trying to write a program that takes a string, breaks it up into characters, and prints each character backwards. I sort of see what the problem is, I just am not sure how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //takes a string and prints all the letters backwards all on one line

    String fruit = "apple";
    backwards(fruit);
    }

public static void backwards(String theFruit) {
    int length = theFruit.length() - 1;
    int counter = 0;
    while(length > counter) {
        char theCharacter = theFruit.charAt(length);
        System.out.println(theCharacter);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

For some reason it just prints all one letter and I am not sure why.

Comment: length never changes and you always output the char at `length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `length` doesn't change, and you are using the length for your println statement.

Instead of adding to counter at the end of your loop, subtract from length. You should then change your while to check that is `>=` counter:

```
while (length >= counter)
{
    System.out.println(theFruit.charAt(length));
    length--;
}
```

You could also change your loop and use a for loop instead:

```
for (int i = length; i >= 0; i--)
{
    System.out.println(theFruit.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest approach for your task is to use `StringBuilder` class.

```
public static void backwards(String theFruit) {
    return new StringBuilder(theFruit).reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

decrements the `length` in `while` loop. and don't increase `counter` variable.

as :

```
while(length >= counter) {
    char theCharacter = theFruit.charAt(length);
    System.out.println(theCharacter);
    length--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the value of length

```
while(length >= counter) {
        char theCharacter = theFruit.charAt(length);
        System.out.println(theCharacter);
        length--;
}
```

with your approach you are printing the last character everytime because `length` value never changed

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/ZRlZXf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuffer Class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer fruit = new StringBuffer("apple");
    System.ouyt.println(fruit.reverse());
    }
```